# How to open all txt files in a directory and count the number of occurrences of a word in the C language

Tags: c

I'm trying to count the number of occurrences of a word in various text files but I can't open these files. I have a directory with this file path : "C:\Users\matti\example", inside the example directory there are 2 text files that contain some words.

I tried to change the directory to another file path but the result is the same.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <string.h>
 #include <sys/types.h>
 #include <dirent.h>
 #include <unistd.h>
 #include <errno.h>

 #define BUFFERSIZE 1000

/* Function declarations */
int countOccurrences(FILE *fptr, const char *word);


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int wCount;
    DIR *FD;
    struct dirent* in_file;
    FILE  *entry_file;
    char dirPath[100];
    char word[50];

    /* Input word to search in file */
    printf("Enter word to search in file: ");
    scanf("%s", word);

    /* Input directory path */
    printf("Enter dir path: ");
    scanf("%s", dirPath); 

    /* Scanning the in directory */                                                                                                                                                                                               
    FD = opendir (dirPath);
    if (FD == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Failed to open input directory - %s\n", strerror(errno));

        return 1;
    }
    while ((in_file = readdir(FD)))
    {
        /* On Linux/Unix we don't want current and parent directories
         * On Windows machines too, thanks Greg Hewgill
         */
        //printf("%s\n", in_file->d_name);
        if (!strcmp (in_file->d_name, "."))
            continue;
        if (!strcmp (in_file->d_name, ".."))
            continue;
        /* Open directory entry file for common operation */    
        entry_file = fopen(in_file->d_name ,"r");

        if (entry_file==NULL)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error : Failed to open entry file - %s\n", strerror(errno));
            return 1;
        }
        //search occurrences of word
        wCount = countOccurrences(entry_file, word);
        printf("'%s' is found %d times in file.", word, wCount);
        wCount=0;
        fclose(entry_file);
    }
    return 0;
}

int countOccurrences(FILE *fptr, const char *word)
{
    char str[BUFFERSIZE];
    char *pos;
    int index, count;
    count = 0;

    // Read line from file till end of file.
    while(fgets(str,BUFFERSIZE,fptr)!=NULL)
    {   
        index = 0;

        // Find next occurrence of word in str
        while ((pos = strstr(str + index, word)) != NULL)
        {

            // Index of word in str is
            // Memory address of pos - memory
            // address of str.
            index = (pos - str) + 1;
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

The result of the code execution in command prompt in Windows 10 is:

```
Enter word to search in file: ciao
Enter dir path: C:\Users\matti\example
Error : Failed to open entry file - No such file or directory
```

Could anyone help me, please?

[image: Images]

Resolved ! 
I had to concatenate the directory path with the file name for the fopen function.

```
    /* Concatenate string to make the completePath for function fopen*/
    char completePath [50];
    strcat(completePath,dirPath);
    strcat(completePath,"\\");
    strcat(completePath,in_file->d_name);
    /* Open directory entry file for common operation */
    entry_file = fopen(completePath, "r");
```

Comment: Are you typing the file path? Is it stored as a string literal somewhere?

Comment: What are you typing in for the path?

Comment: If you have those back-slashes in a defined C string, they need to be "escaped" like "C:\\Users\\matti\\example"

Comment: Just adding a debug printf in your while loop could help you to understand what you are actually trying to open.

Comment: OT: regarding: `int main(int argc, char **argv)`  Since the parameters are not being used, the compiler will output 2 messages about unused parameters.  You can eliminate those messages by using the other valid `main()` signature: `int main( void )`

Comment: before opening a file, the code needs to check that it isn't a symbolic link nor another 'sub' directory.

Comment: OT: regarding: `scanf("%s", word);`  1) when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.  Note: those functions return the number of successful input format conversion specifiers.  2) when using the input format conversion specifiers: `%s` and/or `%[...]`  always include a MAX_CHARACTERS modifier that is one less than the length of the input buffer as those specifiers always append a NUL byte to the input.  This avoids a buffer overflow and the resulting undefined behavior.